# An operator symbol starting with a colon is a constructor

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell. From Haskell 2010 documentation:

> - An operator symbol starting with a colon is a constructor.
> - An operator symbol starting with any other character is an ordinary identifier.

I don't understand first phrase. I know exist *data constructors* and *class type constructors*. What constructor this case? Maybe I need a code sample.

Comment: An lowercase alphanumeric identifier is to an uppercase identifier like a (non-`:`) symbolic operator to a symbol starting with a colon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define stuff like

```
data Symbolic n
   = Constant n
   | Variable String
   | Symbolic n :+ Symbolic n
   | Symbolic n :* Symbolic n
  deriving (Show)
```

> GHCi> let v = Variable; c = Constant
>   GHCi> c 2 :* v"a" :+ c 3
>       (Constant 2 :* Variable "a") :+ Constant 3

That's what the first phrase refers to.

Comment: thank you. I don't understand two last rows in your code. Can you expand it for me?

Comment: Try out the example in ghci.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand advantage of such behavior yet.

Answer (score 4):

> I know exist data constructors and class type constructors. What constructor this case?

In standard Haskell only data constructors can be symbolic and type names must be alphanumeric. If you enable the GHC extension TypeOperators, type names can be symbolic as well, allowing you to define type constructors that start with `:`.

Comment: I want to try it.  How can I enable the `TypeOperators` extension?

Comment: @Bush You can add the `-XTypeOperators` flag to your call to ghc or ghci. You can also add `{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}` to the beginning of a Haskell file to get the same effect without any compiler options.

Comment: I add it and rename `Symbolic` to `Symbolic#`. But ghci doesn't load it.

Comment: @Bush A name needs to either be all symbolic or all alphanumeric. And as mentioned symbolic constructor names need to start with a colon (otherwise it's a type variable). So you'd need to rename `Symbolic` to something like `:-*` or some other combination of symbols starting with a colon. Also remember that symbolic names are used infix when not enclosed in parentheses, so it'd be either `data a :-* b = ...` or `data (:-*) n = ...`.

Comment: {-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
data (:-*) n
   = Constant n
   | Variable String
   | (:-*) n :+ (:-*) n
   | (:-*) n :* (:-*) n
  deriving (Show)

Comment: this compiles fine but don't working:     λ: let n = (:+) (:-* 10) (:-* 20)

<interactive>:77:15:
    Not in scope: data constructor `:-*'
    Perhaps you meant `:*' (line 6)

Comment: @Bush In the code you've shown, you defined the data constructors `:+` and `:*`, but you're trying to use `:-*`, which you didn't define anywhere. Something like `let n :: (:-) Integer = Constant 1 :+ Constant 2` should work (the type signature is optional, of course, but this way the type constructor appears in the code).

Comment: @sepp2k, surely you meant data constructors? With TypeOperators `data a +++ b = a :*** b` is totally allowed, while `data a +++ b = a *** b` isn't.