# How to use ((.).(.)) infix?

Tags: haskell, operators

As is known:

```
((.).(.)) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c
```

I can use this compound operator prefix-style like this:

```
((.).(.)) f g
```

But it appears I cannot use it infix like this:

```
f ((.).(.)) g
```

Is there a way to use this infix style without defining another operator or using a predefined one in a package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't.

Only two kinds of infix operator exist in haskell:

1. A single token that is one or more operator symbols. For all the operator symbols please read [What characters are permitted for haskell operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548170/what-characters-are-permitted-for-haskell-operators)
2. A single identifier between two backticks. An identifier is a token that satisfies certain conditions: please read https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4

So `<$>` is a legal infix operator, and `` `f` ``, but not `` `f x` ``. To test if something is a single token try `lex "YOUR_TOKEN"`. It's a good test with three exceptions (reference from [the documentation of `Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lex)):

- Qualified names are not handled properly
- Octal and hexadecimal numerics are not recognized as a single token
- Comments are not treated properly

Comment: What's interesting is this:  `:t ((.).(.)) undefined undefined` yields 
`((.).(.)) undefined undefined :: a -> a1 -> c` and `:t undefined (.).(.) undefined` yields `undefined (.).(.) undefined :: (a -> b) -> c` in GHCI.

Comment: @Ana This one is even more complicated. An operator in `()` are treated as a normal named function, also function application (white space) has higher precedence than function composition `.`, so `undefined (.) . (.) undefined` is actually `(undefined (.)) . ((.) undefined)`.

Comment: In `undefined (.)`, `undefined` is expanded to `((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)) -> v'` where `v'` is free, so `undefind (.)` has type `v'` just like `undefined` itself. In `(.) undefined`, `undefined` is expanded to `b' -> c'` so `(.) undefined` is resolved to type `(a' -> b') -> (a' -> c')`, by applying the middle `.` `v'` expended to `(a' -> c') -> r'`, so the result type is in form `(a' -> b') -> r'`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. An infix operator can only be either

- An actual named infix. Indeed it's common to define

  ```
  (.:) :: (c->d) -> (a->b->c) -> a->b->d
  (.:) = (.).(.)
  ```

  locally.
- A named function in backticks.