# Haskell own instance typeclass

Tags: class, haskell, instance, where-clause, typeclass

I need to declare my own typeclass but I dont understand why there is the (==).

```
data Egg = Soft | Hard

instance Eq Egg where
(==)
```

I did not find anything where the (==) is used in an instance, only in a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to have an instance of `Eq` is:

```hs
data Egg = Soft | Hard deriving Eq
```

The hard way (with more control):

```hs
data Egg = Soft | Hard

instance Eq Egg where
  Soft == Soft = True
  Hard == Hard = True
  _    == _    = False
```

**UPD**: Since the equality function (==) as an operator seem to be the confusing bit, here is the same instance written with a prefix notation:

```hs
data Egg = Soft | Hard

instance Eq Egg where
  (==) Soft Soft = True
  (==) Hard Hard = True
  (==) _    _    = False
```

As a quick reminder: operator are infix (in between terms) by default, and functions are prefix (before terms) by default. To make an operator prefix it is surrounded by `()`, to make a function infix it is surrounded by ``` `` ```. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548170/what-characters-are-permitted-for-haskell-operators) is a thread talking about which characters are used for operator vs functions.

Comment: thats what i thought aswell but they already wrote instance Eq Egg where (==) and I need to complete the code. The (==) confuses me so much

Comment: Are you confused about the operator (==) ? I'll edit my solution to show a prefix version

Comment: I'm so dumb, thanks for your answer! Totally forgot that that is a prefix

Answer (score 1):

I assume you’re trying to make an *instance* of the standard typeclass `Eq` for your custom datatype. The `Eq` class is defined as:

```
class Eq a where

  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  a == b = not (a /= b)

  (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  a /= b = not (a == b)
```

That is, it defines two methods `==` and `/=` (which happen to be operators), and provides default implementations of each one in terms of the other. So to make an instance of `Eq` for your own type, you need to provide an implementation of one or both of these functions (`==` or `/=`) for your type. Note that the body of the `instance` must be indented.

```
instance Eq Egg where
  Soft == Soft = True
  Hard == Hard = True
  _ == _ = False
```

Just as you can *use* a Haskell operator in prefix form by wrapping it in parentheses, e.g., `(==) 1 1`, you can also *implement* an operator definition in prefix form:

```
instance Eq Egg where
  (==) Soft Soft = True
  (==) Hard Hard = True
  (==) _ _ = False
```

You could even use a `case` if you so desired:

```
instance Eq Egg where
  (==) a b = case (a, b) of
    (Soft, Soft) -> True
    (Hard, Hard) -> True
    _ -> False
```

Note that these are all the same as the instance that would be generated for you automatically with `deriving`:

```
data Egg = Soft | Hard
  deriving (Eq)
```