# Pre-defined infix operator list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Basically, I need to define infix operator for function composition, flipped `g . f` manner.

```
(#) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
(#) = flip (.)

infixl 9 #
```

Here, temporarily, I just have chosen the symbol: `#`, but I'm not certain this choice is not problematic in terms of collision to other definitions.

The weird thing is somehow I could not find a Pre-defined infix operator list in Haskell.

I want the composition operator as concise as possible, hopefully, a single character like `.`, and if possible, I want to make it `&`. Is it OK?

Is there any guidance or best pracice tutorial? Please advise.

Related Q&A:

[What characters are permitted for Haskell operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548170/what-characters-are-permitted-for-haskell-operators)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't see a list of Haskell built-in operators for the same reason you don't see a list of all built-in functions. They're everywhere. Some are in `Prelude`, some are in `Control.Monad`, etc., etc. Operators aren't special in Haskell; they're ordinary functions with neat syntax. And Haskellers are generally pretty operator-happy in general. Spend any time inside your favorite lens library and you'll find plenty of [amusing-looking operators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-60--37--64--126-).

In terms of `(#)`, it might be best to avoid. I don't know of any built-in operators called that, but `#` can be [a bit special](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/magic_hash.html) when it comes to parsing. Specifically, a compiler extension enables `#` at the end of ordinary identifiers, and GHC defines a lot of built-in (primitive) types following this practice. For instance, `Int` is the usual (boxed) integer type, whereas `Int#` is a primitive integer. Most people don't need to interface with this directly, but it is a use that `#` has in Haskell that would be confused slightly by the addition of your operator.

Your `(#)` operator is called [`(>>>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-62--62--62-) in Haskell, and it works on all `Category` instances, including functions. Its companion is `(<<<)`, the generalization of `(.)` to all `Category` instances. If three characters is too long for you, I've seen it called `(|>)` in some other languages, but Haskell already uses that operator for [something else](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:-124--62-). If you're not using `Data.Sequence`, you could use that operator. But personally, I'd just go with `(>>>)`. Any Haskeller will recognize it pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks! Very informative. How about `&`??

Comment: [`(&)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) is already `flip ($)`.

Comment: Ooops. and right I found `>>>` and actually thought too long. Do you have any recommendations? Obviously, `+` is not. By the way `|>` is pipe operator not composition.

Comment: Personally, I don't think "reverse composition" is worth a valuable one-letter symbol, when regular composition already has one. If you're code golfing, use `(#)` since it's just for sport. If you're writing code in the large, then just use `(>>>)` since the extra two characters shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. Appeciated.

Comment: You can use [`(;) = (>>>)`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskelltil/comments/emwl7c/u037e_is_a_valid_operator/) ;)

Comment: @Iceland_jack Thanks for your input! Yeah, I've read [Alternative notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Alternative_notations) in the Wikipedia article. It would be nice to use instead, but tricky to use  Greek character ;)

Comment: @Iceland_jack I was going to object before reading the link. But now... I won't lie, I kind of like it, even if it's not as inconvenient to type.

Comment: Just make sure you are using a font that distinguishes it from an ordinary semicolon.

Comment: You can use the chunky semicolon `⨾`, they are fun to try out and don't have to be used professionally, I personally stick to ascii

Comment: early categoricians tried to fix the absurd `.` mathematic notation and used `⨾` which they called "natural composition". `.` is the "wrong" way. they would have spared some errors..

Comment: `|>` is used in Ocaml, F#, and a few other languages. `&` is here but `|>` is more standard in programming. `⨾` in maths

Comment: @nicolas Totally 100% agreed. That's the main point of this question!